# SSL Certifcate in Apache Webserver running in Docker Container not Working

Tags: docker, apache, ssl, openssl

I've created an docker Container with an Apache Webserver running on it. The Images is from httpd:2.4.41. I've created an private key and certificate with the following command

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /mnt/hgfs/services/apachebinaries/server/conf/ssl/server.key -x509 -out /mnt/hgfs/services/apachebinaries/server/conf/ssl/certificate.crt
```

Then i configured my httpd.conf with the following paths:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.key
   # Weitere Konfigurationsoptione
</VirtualHost>
```

(the paths are correctly mounted from the host system to the docker container)

Then i puplished the ports from the docker to the host machine in my docker compose file.

But if i want to access the port with the correkt ip adress i get the following output from my browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEGCt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen to me few days back and it was related to missing `Listen 443`.

So in your `httpd.conf` add the `Listen 443` before the `VirtualHost`, like:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.key
   # Weitere Konfigurationsoptione
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find more information over on the HTTPD Documentation page, the ["How This Works With Virtual Hosts"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/bind.html)

And here is the before and after adding the `Listen 443`

Before:

```bash
$ curl -v https://localhost:443/ --insecure
*   Trying ::1:443...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443
```

After:

```bash
$ curl -v https://localhost:443/ --insecure
*   Trying ::1:443...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  start date: Jun 28 13:25:20 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 28 13:25:20 2023 GMT
*  issuer: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 13:29:59 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d
< Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
< ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 45
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The `--insecure` is just because it's a Self-Signed Certificate.